# Mousemove gets fired only when mouse is over div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Why is the `mousemover` event fired only when the mouse is over `#cursor`?

```js
function test(event) {
  console.log(42);
}
```

```css
#cursor{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div onmousemove="test(event)">
  <div id="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: On Chrome on the Mac (latest) I see the event firing when the cursor is to the right of the cursor. The box model there allows the container DIV to extend the full width of the container, so I see the event firing regardless of being on the #cursor div or not. Could you please add the browsers you're seeing the behavior? What browser only shows the event when hovering over #cursor and not the container DIV?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this decision will suit you. Good luck.

Fires an event on `<div class = "bigbrother">` it with a blue background, as well as over all the elements that it includes.

```js
function test(event) {
  console.log(42);
}
```

```css
#cursor{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
}
.bigbrother{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbrother" onmousemove="test(event)">
  <div id="cursor"></div>
</div>
```